# Cálculo de porcentajes

Tags: c#, asp.net, array, .net

Hola estoy haciendo un programa el cual llena 2 `listView` el primero con las notas aprobadas y la segunda con notas reprobadas ahora quiero sacar el porcentaje de alumnos aprobados y reprobados y llenarlos en un `label`.

Este es mi código ya hice la formula para el promedio pero el `label` me devuelve 0 como resultado.

```
private void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int porcentaje = 0;
    // Codifique
    for (short intValor = 0; intValor < 100; intValor++) {
        intNumeros[intValor] = objRandom.Next(0, 21);
        if (intNumeros[intValor] > 12) {
            lstAprobados.Items.Add(intNumeros[intValor]);
            porcentaje = (intNumeros[intValor] / 100) * 100;


        } else {
            lstDesaprobados.Items.Add(intNumeros[intValor]);
        }
        lblApro.Text = porcentaje.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba a dividir por `100.0` en lugar de `100`. Si los datos de la lista son enteros, al dividir por 100 hará la división entera (es decir, sin decimales) y saldrá 0.

Comment: hola @abulafia cambie el valor de 100 a 100.0 pero por alguna razon me imprime el ultimo valor de los numeros aleatorios que aparecen en el listview

Comment: ¿Has hecho debug de la lista de enteros aleatorios? Puede ser que te esté dando problemas en la generación de los mismos. Más info: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar tienes un gran error en tu formula de porcentaje.

He aqui un ejemplo de como debe hacerse uno:

```
int tam=100;
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
    sum+=objRandom.Next(0, 21);
}
int porcentaje=(sum/tam)*100;
```

Entonces, si notas en el ejemplo el calculo del porcentaje es de la **sumatoria dividido entre el tamaño multiplicado por 100** y este es calculado al terminar de sumar los valores.

**Segundo:** En `C#` la división  con `/` siempre nos entrega la parte **entera** de la división, ademas de que haces la asignación de tu porcentaje en cada iteracion, razón por la cual tu resultado siempre es cero.

**Te explico:**

```
intNumeros[intValor] = objRandom.Next(0, 21);//esta linea codigo solo te entrega numeros entre 0 y 21.
```

Entonces  `intNumeros[intValor]` siempre tendra un valor menor a 100, por esto las operaciones siempre seran como estas:

```
porcentaje = (21 / 100) * 100;// porcentaje=0
porcentaje = (17 / 100) * 100;// porcentaje=0
porcentaje = (0 / 100) * 100;// porcentaje=0
porcentaje = (2 / 100) * 100;// porcentaje=0
```

Y asi con todos los casos.

**Solucion:(Mejorada)**

```
private void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int porcentaje_apro = 0;
    int porcentaje_repro = 0;
    int suma=0;
    int con=0;
    // Codifique
    for (short intValor = 0; intValor < 100; intValor++) {
        intNumeros[intValor] = objRandom.Next(0, 21);
        if (intNumeros[intValor] > 12) {
            lstAprobados.Items.Add(intNumeros[intValor]);
            con++;
        } else {
            lstDesaprobados.Items.Add(intNumeros[intValor]);
        }

    }
    porcentaje_apro=con; // en tu caso especial, ya que tu población es de 100;
    porcentaje_repro=100-porcentaje_apro;//seguimos con tu caso especial.

    /*En cualquier otro caso tu debes de hacer el la operacion de ej:
      poblacion=250;
      porcentaje_apro=(con/poblacion)*100 
      porcentaje_repro=100-porcentaje_apro;

    */

    lblApro.Text = "El porcentaje de alumnos aprobados es: ":porcentaje_apro.ToString()+" y la de reprobados es :"+porcentaje_repro.ToString();
}
```

La solucion fue editada por lo que dices en: **quiero sacar el porcentaje de alumnos aprobados y reprobados**, mil disculpas si antes publique otra "cosa", a veces estoy cansado de tanto programar y no leo de forma correcta el problema que tienen perdon.

Comment: Hola trate de hacerlo como tu hiciste pero el resultado del porcentaje me sale 1500% o 1600%

Comment: intenta trabajar con doubles y no con int, ademas debes de notar que si necesitas el 100%100 de eso solo debes de multiplicar por 1

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con tu respuesta. Dices _En C# la división con / siempre nos entrega la parte entera de la división_. Eso no es cierto. El problema es que si trabajas con enteros, por supuesto que que no te va a dar decimales, pero eso no tiene nada que ver con el operador `/`.Y de hecho, la solución que aportas al final es incorrecta, por mucho que multipliques el resultado por 100, ya la division `(suma/i)` al ser enteros no va a dar decimales.El problema de base es que hay que usar el tipo correcto si necesitas trabajar con decimales.

Comment: @Pikoh, estoy de acuerdo contigo, razon por la cual edite la respuesta, haber si esta sirve.

Comment: @douglas, edite la respuesta, espero esta te sirva.

Comment: Tu solución mejorada funciona solo por el hecho de que parece que el op tiene 100 notas, pero la clave del cálculo de porcentajes en cualquier otra situación es que hay que usar `float` en lugar de `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
porcentaje = (intNumeros[intValor] / 100) * 100;
```

Por un lado, estás usando números enteros

Si `intNumeros[intValor]` es 5 => 5 / 100 = 0 * 100 = 0...

Por otro lado, para calcular el porcentaje de aprobados, debes coger el total de notas (aprobadas y no) y dividirlo por el número de aprobados... Eso si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer...

No declares el array de intNumeros como enteros, pues al dividir puede llevarte a confusión... o si lo haces, atento a los décimales, que no existen.

Salu2

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas 4 cosas:

1. cantidad de alumnos aprobados(esto lo puedes obtener mediante una query ejemplo:

   var aprobados = db.Alumnos.Where(a=>a.Nota >= 60)
   por lo que la cantidad de aprobados sería aprobados.Count()
2. cantidad de desaprobados. lo mismo que el paso 1 pero <
3. Total de alumnos

   var total = db.Alumnos.Count()
4. Tu formula de %

   al despejar la formula original te queda que:

   var porc_aprobados = (aprobados*100)/total;

   var porc_desap = (desaprobados*100)/total

espero te sea de ayuda